# letters occurence in a string

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

How to count character occurrences in a string?

For example, say I have the following input string:

```
test text
```

output should be:

```
t  4
e  2
s  1
x  1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without compiling and testing it something like the linq below should do the trick:

```
from c in str
group by c into g
select new { letter= g.Key, count= g.Count()}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var str = "abc cccdd";

var group = from c in str
            group c by c into g
            select g;

foreach(var g in group)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}\t{1}", g.Key, g.Count()));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to perform this, same as Luke McGregor's answer just differnet syntax

```
string mystring = "test text";
var result = mystring.GroupBy(ch => ch).Select(a => new {chr = a.Key, count = a.Count()});
```

Comment: *Different* meaning **Method Syntax**. Whereas the answer by Luke McGregor is implemented using **Query Syntax**. For a comparison of these two approaches, see [Query Syntax and Method Syntax in LINQ (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

**Recursive solution**

Note that is going to count the white spaces also . You could remove the white spaces before.

```
public static void GroupString(string str) 
    {
        if (str.Length == 1)
            Console.WriteLine(str[0] + " 1");
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str[0] +  " "+ str.Count(c => c == str[0]));
            GroupString(str.Replace(str[0].ToString(),""));
        }
    }
```